# What are the advantages of using private cloud over a data center?

Tags: cloud

I want to know the advantages of a private cloud over a traditional data center. From my view, a private cloud is just a cloud owned and operated by one organization. Because of that, there are no gain in capital cost or operating cost since this organization will need to burden all the cost of using this cloud. Elasticity also doesnt make sense since all the infrastructure are devoted to one customer. So it seems to me moving into a private cloud is no different than building a traditional data center . Can anybody help me to clarify this question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of advantages with private cloud. We are implementing private cloud in my organization as I speak. Below are some that I think on top of my mind.

1. My organization is a banking and financial services organization. Such organizations that are bound with lot of legal compliance w.r.t data security etc cannot easily decide to go to a public cloud. That will put their data security at risk w.r.t policies. Private is the best organization. That is also one reason why cloud providers like Microsoft etc came with private cloud idea.
2. With private cloud developers, specially from agile teams can easily create sites for dev test and qa test from cloud management interface without the interference of infrastructure teams. They can deploy, start, stop, shutdown etc with controlled access. So things are done faster and there is a lot of savings in operational costs.
3. Even the infrastructure personnel will get a chance to be pro-active with respect to resource procurement. Instead of waiting for a request from the project managers for new servers etc. The infrastructure team can continuously monitor resource consumption and add resources proactively. Makes their life more easier.
4. Performance. In my organization in order to reap the benefits of cloud they agreed to change the legacy source code into SOA based architecture. Which allows horizontal scalability and lot more advantages of SOA based architecture.
5. Huge organizations have cost centers. I mean a department pays another department even when they are in same organization. In my organization after implementation, the infrastructure cost center is going to bill every other consuming cost center per usage basis. In long run that will bring lot of savings, accountability and flexibility.
6. Some private clouds are free for instance Microsoft Azure Pack. Organizations which already use windows server can simply bring the private cloud up and start using it if not for production atleast for test environment, intranet etc. They also offer support to LDAP, GIT etc

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest benefit of a private cloud is you only pay for what you use at a very effective price.  If you build a data center the upfront costs are huge!!!  In most cases the costs are prohibitive to the problem you are trying to solve.  For my work I do research so cloud computing is perfect.  I develop my algorithm on a small scale and when it is ready I move it to the cloud run it on a large number of computers for a few days then write a paper.  Research organizations are happy with this model because they only pay for what they need, it is a way to share the high upfront costs with many people.  Elasticity in my mind refers to the fact that I can grow or shrink based on my computation needs.  Another form of elasticity would be I could use a mix of operating systems and applications making it elastic.  I hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Private clouds are mostly for a specific purpose of the user. It helps in enabling the user to invest only for what is required for their work. Plus it help improve the system's ability to take up loads thus reducing any crashes. search the internet you ll get a fair idea of the differences.